# PHP file upload in another directory

Tags: php, linux, file-upload

I am uploading files in php. The upload directory is

```
/var/www/html/oop/uploads/images/
```

But after uploading when i open the folder, it contains no image whatsoever. But when I try to include the image in a web page like this,

`<img src="http://localhost/oop/uploads/images/1472722513.jpg" />`

it is being included in the web page and works fine. I don't know how this is possible, I am using ubuntu 16.04.

my upload code

```
$file_path = '/var/www/html/oop/uploads/images/';

$name = $_SERVER['image']['name'];
$name = explode('.', $name);
$name = array_reverse($name);

$file_name = time() . '.' . $name[0];
$temporary_location = $_SERVER['image']['name']['tmp_name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($temporary_location, $file_path.$file_name)) {
    echo "all ok";
} else {
    echo $_SERVER['image']['name']['error'];
}
```

Comment: Did you Checked hidden Files in uploaded folder?

Comment: Have you check how looks like the $file_path.$file_name looks like before uploading it?

Comment: yes i have and it is as it should be

Comment: i searched using the file name in the computer and got it in a folder in `/proc/3916/cwd`. this folder contains all the images that i have uploaded. i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand the concept of document root. A webserver does not reflect the local file system to public, mainly for security reasons.

When you are able to reference /var/www/../image.jpeg in your web browser, this actually points to a path relative to your document root e.g. `/var/www/html/var/www/images/image.png`

Read more about document root here

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#documentroot